# Why is changing "transform" property on DOM element slow in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, css, css-animations

My understanding is that changing the `transform` property on DOM elements should be fast, since it won't force layout or repainting. But things seem a bit sluggish, and profiling points towards changing `transform` as the culprit.

I have this code which updates the DOM element of a particle per its properties:

```
const applyCSSToParticle = (particle) => {
  const { elem, x, y, z, rot } = particle

  elem.style.transform =
    'translateX(' +
    x +
    'px) translateY(' +
    y +
    'px) rotate(' +
    rot +
    'deg) scale(' +
    z +
    ')'
}
```

And it's called by this function:

```
const applyPhysics = () => {
  requestAnimationFrame(applyPhysics)
  particles.forEach((particle, i) => {
    const { id, elem, text, x, y, z, xVel, yVel, zVel, rot, rVel } = particle

    particle.x += xVel * z
    particle.y += yVel * z
    particle.z = Math.min(z + zVel, maxZ)
    particle.rot += rVel
    applyCSSToParticle(particle)
  })
```

When I profile my code, I'm seeing that about 30% of the time is spent in `applyCSSToParticle()`. Any ideas on how to speed this up?

Comment: could you use will change css property

Comment: I tried adding `will-change: transform` to the particle class. It didn't seem to help.

Comment: The question requires too much guesswork.  See: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)  "Provide all parts someone else needs to reproduce your problem in the question itself"

Comment: you should not use transforms on many elements at the same time. It looks like the browser is creating layers for each element and using up all the memory. You can add a translateZ(0.001px) property, but I don't know if that would help. It will be better if you work with a canvas or three js. You can find many examples like https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_points_sprites.html.

Comment: Thanks @VladykoD, rendering everything in one canvas rather than many elements with CSS transforms fixed the issue.